# Como Montar um Jtable com ResultSet?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, resultset

Tenho um exemplo:

```
Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" },{ "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" } };
Object columnNames[] = { "Posição", "Nome", "Pontuação" };
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(255, 400);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Eu preciso fazer o `rowData` receber um `ResultSet`, não domino java, e ate agora no `while` não consegui fazer o `rowData` receber meu `ResultSet`

```
if(rs != null) {
    while(rs.next()) {
        // rowData = ?? 
    }
}
```

Comment: queres obter os dados que estão na `jtabel`?

Comment: não, eu quero que o rowData receba meu rs @jsantos1991

Comment: tenta isto: `DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();` depois usas o `tm` para inserir tipo: `tm.addRow(new Object[]{new String("aaaaa"), new String("bbbb"), new String("ccccc"), new String("ddddd")});`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui dessa maneira:

```
String[] colunasTabela = new String[]{ "Posição", "Nome", "Pontuação" };  
DefaultTableModel modeloTabela = new DefaultTableModel(null,colunasTabela);

if(rs != null) {
    while(rs.next()) {
        modeloTabela.addRow(new String[] {  
                rs.getInt("ranking"),  
                rs.getString("nome"),  
                rs.getInt("score")
            }); 
    }
}

JTable table = new JTable();
table.setModel(modeloTabela);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(255, 400);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Ainda bem que conseguiu, só uma sugestão procure por tableModel, um bom exemplo é http://devsv.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/como-implementar-um-tablemodel/